# Read complex array from php

Tags: php, arrays

I get this array in response from webservice, so How do I read it in a foreach cycle? or some easy way to read it. The [group] they are more than 12 [id]
there is.

```
Array 
( [response] => Array ( 
    [single] => Array ( [parameters] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => msgCode [value] => 0101 ) 
                                                [1] => Array ( [name] => msgDesc [value] => OK ) 
                                                [2] => Array ( [name] => status [value] => 1) 
                                                [3] => Array ( [name] => message [value] => Normal) ) ) 
    [group] => Array ( [id] => N4BD767 [parameters] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => idFee [value] => 000 ) echo
                                                                [1] => Array ( [name] => typeFee [value] => Cuota) 
                                                                [2] => Array ( [name] => entryDate [value] => 2014-12-17T14:06:47-03:00 ) 
                                                                [3] => Array ( [name] => expirationDate [value] => 2015-12-05T00:00:00-03:00) 
                                                                [4] => Array ( [name] => amountOrigin [value] => 221980) 
                                                                [5] => Array ( [name] => surcharges [value] => 1856) 
                                                                [6] => Array ( [name] => entity [value] => ONLINE) 
                                                                [7] => Array ( [name] => feeStatus [value] => inicial ) 
                                                                [8] => Array ( [name] => tranNumber [value] => 27) ) ) ) )
```

Comment: and what's your attempt?

Comment: Do you want to extract "[group]" array values?

Comment: What you want from the array actually, if you have specific need please let me know, or if you want a number of columns from the array specify that .

Comment: What do you want to extract from this array?

Comment: Hello everyone, yes I need every [group] has a [id] and every [id] has a 9 sub array. and I was trying that without luckly day.

foreach($result['group'] as $dataset){
 $idgroup=$dataset[id];

 $arr = isset($dataset['parameters'])? $dataset['parameters']: $dataset;
 
 for ($row=0; $row<9 ; $row++){
  echo "Name  = ".$arr[$row]["name"]."<BR>";
  echo "Value = ".$arr[$row]["value"]."<BR>";

 }
}

Comment: ok I found array_walk_recursive and it work, just I want to create a new array, and I did a function with a reference var (array) instead a global array but does not work.  
function fnc_pusharray($item,$key,&$output)  
{
 $output[] = array($key => $item);  
 //inside work, I print out and show information.  
}  
 $output = array('.'=>'.');  
 array_walk_recursive($result, 'fnc_pusharray',$output);  
 echo var_dump($output);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay guys, this is what I did and it work fine. With no foreach.

```
$output = array();  
array_walk_recursive($result, function($item,$key) use (&$output){ 
    array_push($output,$key,$item);
});  
echo var_dump($output);
```